# Parser error in ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net

When I run my simple ASP.NET app (just a single web form) on my up-to-date Windows 7 machine at home, it runs fine. When I upload it to DiscountASP.NET, however, and try to run it, I get the following error (I am copying up all the [few] files manually):

> Could not load type: MyNamespace._Default

I am compiling it in VS2012 and the project targets .NET 4.0. Any ideas what would cause this?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Show us class declaration from code-behind and page tag from ASPX?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Inherits attribute of the Page directive has the underscore before "Default", and also the class declaration in your code behind.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 ....
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Also, in IIS, make sure you have ASP.NET set up for 2.0 or greater and that the default document has _Default.aspx added.

Comment: That makes me wonder something. The folder this simple form is running in is under a site that is running as Classic ASP. In DiscountASP.NET's control panel, I remember having to choose "Classic ASP" somewhere. When I asked them if I could run an ASP.NET alongside the Classic ASP app, they said "yes." Is there something special I would have to do to get this form to run alongside the Classic app? Also, there is no default document. I'm hitting the form directly in the URL.

Comment: Can't help you on the Classic ASP part but this may be the source of your problem. Contact hosting support?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll talk to support later today and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the folder containing the ASP.NET form and making it a "Web Application" in the DiscountASP.NET control panel fixed the problem. After that, the form ran just fine.